# PHP: How do I dynamically create a multidimensional array based on certain values I get?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Using this array as an example:

```
$array = array( 'key1' , 'key2'   );
```

How can I use the array above to create something like this:

```
$multiarray['key1']['key2'] = 'test';
```

This should work regardless of the array count:

```
$array = array( 'key1' , 'key2' , 'key3' , 'key4'   );

$multiarray['key1']['key2']['key3']['key4'] = 'test';
```

Comment: can we know why ?? SO is not a quiz game platform ..Include your try..

Comment: What have you tried!! Have a look [How to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @RohitKumar I am only here to solve an occasional puzzle. :-) I like this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another take, that uses spongeBob as functionname:

```
$inp = ['keyX', 'koyX', 'drip', 'drop'];
$result = spongeBob($inp);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>"; 

function spongeBob($arr){
    $rev = array_reverse($arr);
    $result = 'test';
    foreach ($rev as $oneKey){
        $result = array($oneKey => $result);
    }   
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Will you keep the function name in your production code? ;-)

Comment: I highly doubt it, don't think my intern employer would like that, lol.

Answer (score 0):

A bit out of the scope, but worth mentioning I believe :)

```
$foo = new stdClass;
$foo->foo->bar->baz->qux = "¯\_(ツ)_/¯";

print_r($foo);
```

Output:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [foo] => stdClass Object
        (
            [bar] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [baz] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [qux] => ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
<?php
$ks = [3,2,4,1,4,5,5521,231,3];

var_dump(array_reduce( array_reverse($ks)
                      ,function($carry,$item){ return [$item => $carry];}
                      ,"test"));

/* array(1) {
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [2]=>
    array(1) {
      [4]=>
      array(1) {
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [4]=>
          array(1) {
            [5]=>
            array(1) {
              [5521]=>
              array(1) {
                [231]=>
                array(1) {
                  [3]=>
                  string(4) "test"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
} */
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this one -

```
<?php
$array = array( 'key1' , 'key2' , 'key3' , 'key4'   );
$result=magic();
function magic()
{
global $array;
$key=current($array);
return next($array)?array($key=>magic()):array($key=>'text');

}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "<pre>";

?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [key1] => Array
        (
            [key2] => Array
                (
                    [key3] => Array
                        (
                            [key4] => text
                        )

                )

        )

)
```